# Vaadin 7 Spring MVC Example

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7, vaadin7

I'm trying to develop a **Vaadin 7** application with **Spring MVC** (Not Spring Boot) and I don't understand how to configure it with maven and embedded tomcat 7. Could anyone give me proper example how to configure **spring MVC** application with **vaadin 7** (not latest version)  using maven and embedded tomcat?

Comment: https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-basic-mvc.html this might helps you

Comment: is it working for vaadin 7 version ?

Comment: it is for vaadin 14